# How to pass post id in jquery ajax which uses Jquery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to pass a post_id using ajax. Below is the jquery ajax i am using.

Jquery files : jQuery UI Sortable 1.11.4

.
.
$.post(ajaxurl, {
action: 'update_order',
order: $('#list').sortable('serialize'),

});

.
.

Comment: Where is post_id ? Please elaborate more.

Comment: post_id is an id which is needed to be passed to ajax.

Comment: where is it  ? In your html ? Please update your question with relevant html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some RnD i have prepared a solution for this

$.post(ajaxurl,
{
action: 'update_order',
data: {
'order': $('#list').sortable('serialize'),
'id' : 298
},
});

We can now pass the id 298. The values will be passed as an array.